# Chrome and Chromium crash at login

Tags: login, google-chrome, chromium, crash

As in the title, I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and installed at first chrome-stable but as soon as I try to sign in my account it freezes until it asks me to force quit (chromium web browser does not respond).
I purged it and tried to install at first chrome-unstable then chromium to no avail.
I also tried turning off hardware acceleration, nothing.

Can anybody help?

Comment: I'm having the same issue - are you using 2-factor authentication as well? I'm asking because it seems to hang as soon as I type in my password (but before the 2FA has competed).

Answer (score 2):

Chromium kept crashing for me on Ubuntu 18.04 on the Dual Authentication page for my account that had DualAuth enabled (and in Gmail generally for my other account). I had just installed Chromium, and rebooting seems to resolved the issue for me.

Comment: After a reboot, I found Chrome wanted to unlock my keyring, and then asked if I wanted to save my password, which it was not doing before.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much a fix as a workaround.

In my case it seemed to be related to 2-factor authentication, as `Chromium` would hang immediately after I entered my password (but before I had confirmed the login on my phone).

I worked around this issue by logging into google via a website as opposed to through the browser (somewhat ironically I discovered this by using my google account to sign into this website to comment on this topic).

Anywho, once you're logged in the browser will pick it up and you can enable sync in `Chromium`/`Chrome` without having to log in, thereby bypassing the bit that seems to crash.

I hope this works for you as well!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this situation with Chrome on 20.04 on an Acer Nitro 5. At one point it almost seemed to be solved when I tried logging in first on a personal account before using the corporate account I was trying, but when I restarted Chrome, my profile picture became dim at the top and Google wanted me to report problems with my profile, which I did.

Another thing I tried, which seemed to work briefly, was saying that I was changing my password and then backing out of it.

I really didn't believe that a machine restart could help, but so far it looks like it did!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem disappeared when I logged in to the gnome-keyring.

But the problem is very annoying, because it does not give any clear indication, and the keyring can be hidden on different desktop and Chrome/Chromium stuck even if I put there wrong password or cancel the login.